# how do I use a constructor?

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I just learned about classes in c++ and programmed a code which worked well, but later I've been asked to use a constructor, but i haven't learned about it yet. i'm supposed to upload this today and i would've easily done so if this requirement was taught in class but sadly no.

I've tried modifying the code from what i know after referring the lecture note example but I still am not sure how this constructor thing works or how i'm supposed to implement it. for now I've only tried using it for the lecturer where i pass the value to a constructor function named `SetLecturerName` but I'm not sure what else i'm supposed to do. Would really appreciate it if someone could look into this code and let me know where I went wrong.

the requirement is to use a constructor for both the lecturer and the course name. I thought of solving one first and manage the other alone.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>   //program uses c++ standard string class


    using namespace std;


    class GradeBook{        //gradebook class definition
    //PUBLIC-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------     
        public:


        //COURSE---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        void setCourseName(string name){        //function that sets the course name
            courseName = name;      //store the course name in the object
        }

        string getCourseName(){     //function that gets the course name
            return courseName;      //return the object's courseName
        }


        //LECTURER------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
        /*void setLecturerName(string LecName){     //function that sets the course name
            lecturerName = LecName;     //store the course name in the object
        }*/


        GradeBook(string Lname){
            SetLecturerName(Lname);     //calling the constructor function
        }


        void SetLecturerName(string LecName){       //The constructor function
            lecturerName = LecName;     //store the course name in the object
        }


        string getLecturerName(){       //function that gets the course name
            return lecturerName;        //return the object's courseName
        }   


        //WELCOME MESSAGE------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
        void displayMessage(){      //function that displays a welcome message
            cout << "==================================" << endl;
            cout << "Welcome to the grade book for\n" << getCourseName() << "!" << endl << endl;        //this statement calls getCourseName to get the name of the course this gradebook represents
            cout << "This course is presented by, \n" << getLecturerName() << "." << endl;
            cout << "==================================" << endl;
        }


    //PRIVATE------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        private:
        string courseName;      //course name for this gradebook
        string lecturerName;        //Lecturer name for this gradebook
    };


    int main(){
        string nameOfCourse;        //string of characters to store the course name
        string nameoflecturer;      //string of characters to store the lecturer name
        GradeBook myGradeBook(nameoflecturer);      //create a GradeBook object named myGradeBook


        //COURSE---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        cout << "\nPlease enter the course name:" << endl;
        getline(cin, nameOfCourse);     //read a course name with blanks
        myGradeBook.setCourseName(nameOfCourse);        //set the course name


        //LECTURER-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        cout << "\nPlease enter the Lecturer's name including the title(Ex- Mr.):" << endl;
        getline(cin, nameoflecturer);
        myGradeBook.setLecturerName(nameoflecturer);


        //WELCOME MESSAGE------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        cout << endl;
        myGradeBook.displayMessage();       //display message with new course name
    }
```

Comment: the term "constructor function" does not exist. You do have a constructor and you are using it in the line `GradeBook myGradeBook(nameoflecturer);` hence it isnt clear what you are asking

Comment: Did you look up constructors in any C++ learning material? What exactly is your problem? `GradeBook(string Lname)` is a constructor, `GradeBook myGradeBook(nameoflecturer)` is giving it an empty string. You probably want to **remove** `setCourseName` and `SetLecturerName`, or at least make them `private:`.

Comment: "...and let me know where I went wrong." why do you think there is something wrong in the code? DO you get compiler errors? Runtime errors? Unexpected results? Your tutor had some complaints on your current code?

Comment: Creating an instance of the class always invokes a constructor.   In a class, a constructor is a function that accepts no argument, and has no return type.   The argument list supplies the values.   For example, if a class named `Class` has a constructor that accepts an `int` by value,    a variable definition `Class x(2)` will call that constructor (if it is accessible) and pass the value `2` to it.

Comment: well i did, the previous question was asking to follow a template which already showed how the course name can be displayed using classes (without the use of a constructor) and it asked to add in a lecturername to it the same way. but this question asks to use a constructor. the template given is a completely different thing, plus since it wasn't taught to us properly, i used the previous question and just added a constructor the way i understand. 

i followed the exact way the template showed but doesn't seem to be showwing any result

Answer (score 1):

As your code is now, you first create an instance of `GradeBook` with an empty lecturer, then change the lecturer later when it was read. While this works, it would make more sense to first read the name, then create the object.

So you would create a constuctor like

```
class GradeBook {
// ...
  GradeBook(string lecturer, string course) {
    lecturerName = lecturer;
    courseName = course;
  }
// ...
}
```

or, with an initializer list:

```
  GradeBook(string lecturer, string course) :
    lecturerName(lecturer),
    courseName(course)
  { }
```

and in `main()`:

```
int main() {
    string nameOfCourse;
    string nameoflecturer;

    cout << "\nPlease enter the course name:" << endl;
    getline(cin, nameOfCourse);
    cout << "\nPlease enter the Lecturer's name including the title(Ex- Mr.):" << endl;
    getline(cin, nameoflecturer);

    GradeBook myGradeBook(nameoflecturer, nameOfCourse);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: better use the constructors initializer list for initialization of members rather than assignment in the constructors body

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 true, but I thought it would be confusing to someone who's never heard of constructors before. I'll add it.

Comment: ymmv, I think it is confusing to not show it when using it has clear advantages for almost no cost ;)

Comment: yeah this works too, but apparently this question is so tricky it asks for a get and set function, as ive done in my code. this is so frustrating.